# How can I write a number into a executable from a script

Tags: bash

I have an executable in which I write a number. Also, I have a script.sh that opens the executable. How can I write the number in the executable from the script?

My script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

number=2

./exec

printf '%d\n' $number
```

This does not work. First, the executable finished, after the number is displayed.

Comment: What does "Put a number in an executable" mean here? Pass it as an argument? Write it, physically in the file somewhere (where?)? Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? Like.. could you open the executable with a text editor, write the number, close it, then execute it and that would work, but you want that done in a script... or something?

Comment: This is not done as easily as you think (based on your code). Given `bash` tag, I could assume you're running the `exec` on `linux`? Assuming the `exec` is your own app, try passing the number to the exec as a parameter and print it from within the app: `./exec $number` or return an errorcode from your app and print that in `bash`. Another way to do this is to `export` the `number` as an environment variable, then modify the value of that from within the `exec`, the latter should be relatively easy.

Comment: @JNevill, my best guess is that OP is trying to modify the value of `number` from within `exec` and have that change propagate back to the calling script...

Comment: let's say that if i run ./exec and i write 5, the program will display the value of number + 1. So, in the terminal, it will appear 6. I want to run ./script.sh and have the same result.

Comment: "Write 5"? Where? I still don't get it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Jsx7O

Comment: i want to run the executable in the script and write the value of number. So, if i run ./script.sh, i want to obtain 6

Comment: According to your link, `exec` prints two values (5 and 6)... always? Your script should print the same values.

Comment: When your say `if i run ./exec and i write 5, the program will display the value of number + 1`. What do you mean? Where do you write `5`. Hold a second... Does `exec` ask you to type a value?

Comment: Pass the $number as an argument to exec.  The result can then be set back into variable $number when exec outputs the result.  Look up arguments management for bash.

Comment: Rather than reply in comments, you should be improving the basic quality of your Q. We need to see sample input, required output, your current code solution and output and error messages. Be sure to use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. For more info see  and [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Good luck.

Comment: @Jdamian yes. The exec ask me to type a value and return the value + 1. I want to obtain the same result if I run the script, without type the value. I mean, I want the script put the value in the executable and return the correct answer.

Comment: And do you think we do not have anything else to do than read your mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking to have the script feed a specific number to the executable's standard input.  This is done as follows:

```
echo $number | ./exec
```

Comment: it works! thanks a lot!